# How to display the sentence in display_details?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
    class Pet:
        def __init__(self, name, animal_type, age):
            self.__name = name
            self.__animal_type = animal_type
            self.__age = age

        def set_name(self, name):
            self.__name = name

        def set_animal_type(self, animal_type):
            self.__animal_type = animal_type

        def set_age(self, age):
            self.__age = age

        def get_name(self):
            return self.__name

        def get_animal_type(self):
            return self.__animal_type

        def get_age(self):
            return self.__age

        def display_details(self):
            return "Pet {} is a {}, and it is {} years old".format(self.__name, self.__animal_type, 
self.__age)
```

The problem is up here ^

```
name = input("Enter pet name:")
    animal_type = input("Enter pet type:")
    age = int(input("Enter age of pet:"))
    Pet(name, animal_type, age)
```

I'm trying to display the sentence under display_details but I do not see it in my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created an instance of your Pet class? I.e.:

```
name = input("Enter pet name:")
animal_type = input("Enter pet type:")
age = int(input("Enter age of pet:"))

my_pet = Pet(name, animal_type, age)
print(my_pet.display_details())
```

Comment: Hmm it seems to work for me (I'm using Jupiter Notebook). You may need to explicitly print the returned result, I updated the answer. Otherwise I'm not sure!